# how can i modify and reverse every bit in NSData using swift language ?

Tags: swift, nsdata

how can i modify and reverse every bit in NSData using swift language ?  i want to make something like code confustion.

```
//.....
let tempstring : String = "hello world!" 
let tempnsstring : NSString = tempstring as NSString 
var tempnsdata : NSData! 
tempnsdata = tempnsstring.dataUsingEncoding(encoding) 
//....
```

then .. please tell me how to modify the data in NSData ? give me some hint on coding . thanks

Comment: If your input is "hello, world", what is your expected output?

Comment: i want to explore every byte in nsdata , and reverse the binary code in byte , and then write back to the nsdata for the next operation.

Comment: I'm looking for the exact output. One could take the word reverse a couple of ways. Is the reverse of 'A' (0b01000001) 0b10000010, or is it 0b10111110?

Comment: In any case, the general answer is get the data out of NSData with getbytes into an array, traverse that array doing what you need, then store the result into a new NSData.

Comment: just make it reverse bit code like  0b01000001 into 0b111110  ,   thanks

Comment: can we realize the code with unsafepointer  ？  i just want some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSData` is an immutable type, so you cannot modify its content.

Two alternatives.

(1) Create a new `NSData` with modified content.

```
let tempstring = "hello world!"
let encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
let tempnsdata = tempstring.dataUsingEncoding(encoding)!

var tempbytes: [UInt8] = Array(count: tempnsdata.length, repeatedValue: 0)

tempnsdata.getBytes(&tempbytes, length: tempbytes.count)

for i in tempbytes.indices {
    tempbytes[i] = ~tempbytes[i]
}

let modifiednsdata = NSData(bytes: tempbytes, length: tempbytes.count)
//Use `modifiednsdata`...
```

(2) Create a mutable copy and modify the content in it.

```
let tempstring = "hello world!"
let encoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding
let tempnsdata = tempstring.dataUsingEncoding(encoding)!

let tempnsmutabledata = tempnsdata.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableData

let mutabledataptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(tempnsmutabledata.mutableBytes)

for i in 0..<tempnsmutabledata.length {
    mutabledataptr[i] = ~mutabledataptr[i]
}

//Use `tempnsmutabledata` as `NSData`
```

Comment: Is this for iOS/iPadOS only? For Mac it won't work, for example: Value of type 'Data?' has no member 'mutableCopy'

Comment: @Heitor, this is an old thread written in Swift 3 (or 2) age. You should better start a new thread showing which version of Swift you use.

Comment: It's version 5.1. XCode gives a couple of advices and proposes changes, but it looks like it's related to the fact Im coding for Mac.